Representation and Laplacian on the Heisenberg group
Let  $\pi_{\lambda}$ be the the Schrödinger representations of the Heisenberg group $H=\mathbb  C\times \mathbb R$. For $\varphi\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, we have
$$\pi_{\lambda} (z,t)\varphi(\xi)=e^{i\lambda t} e^{i\lambda(x.\xi+\frac{1}{2}x.y)}\varphi(\xi+y),$$
where $z=x+iy$.
The left invariant vector fields $X, Y$ and $T$ on $H$ are given by
$$X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}y\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\quad Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{2}x\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \quad \text{and}\quad T=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$
The representation $\pi$ of $H$ determines a representation $\pi^*$ of its Lie algebra on the
space of $C^{\infty}$ vectors, which defined by
$$\pi^{*}(X)\phi=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr\rvert_{t=0}\Big(\pi\big(e^{tX}\big)\phi \Bigr)\ $$
for every $X$ in the Lie algebra. Now, From the following two identities
$$\pi^*_\lambda (X)=i\lambda \xi\quad\text{and}\quad \pi^*_\lambda (Y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}$$
how can we deduce that $$\pi^*_\lambda (\mathcal L)=-\Delta+\lambda^2|x|^2,\, ?$$
where $\mathcal L$ is the sublaplacian on $H$ given by $\mathcal L= -\left(X^2+Y^2\right)$ and $\Delta$ is the standard Laplacian on $\mathbb R$, i.e., $\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$.
I think it’s a simple calculation, but I can’t do it. Thank you in adavnce.
